# Cannot use already compiled C library using cgo in Golang application?

Tags: c, go, shared-libraries, cgo

I am trying to wrap a C library in Golang. I am trying to call a C function in an already compiled library. I have both a `.a` file and a `.so` library file.

Where do I need to place the library files and how do i tell `cgo` that I am using these libraries?

I am rather a novice when it comes to C. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can link to C libraries (that what cgo is mainly for). What problem are you having?

Comment: I want to call a client library but am unsure where to place the library so that I can reference it in go? And then how to tell go where the library is?

Comment: There's a cgo directive specifically for pkg-config, `#cgo pkg-config`, and there's also `#cgo LDFLAGS`: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/. You can use either of those to tell the linker how to find the libraries.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987643/how-to-link-golang-package-to-an-existing-c-project-using-go-from-c-on-windows

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example? So if I have a library hello.a and put it in my go src in a folder called lib how do i set this up?

Comment: @Westy10101: if you want to package the C library with your source, look for `{SRCDIR}` in the cgo documentation I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain it with this sample:

First build `libhello.a` using `./libs/m.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h> 

extern uint64_t Add(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

For this test sample `libhello.a` is inside `./libs/` :

```
m.go
└───libs
    m.c
    libhello.a
```

---

Then `go build` this `m.go` working sample:

```
package main

//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -lhello
//#include <stdint.h>
//extern uint64_t Add(uint64_t a, uint64_t b);
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.Add(C.uint64_t(10), C.uint64_t(20))) // 30
}
```

output:

```
30
```

---

> When the cgo directives are parsed, any occurrence of the string
>   ${SRCDIR} will be replaced by the absolute path to the directory
>   containing the source file. This allows pre-compiled static libraries
>   to be included in the package directory and linked properly. For
>   example if package foo is in the directory /go/src/foo:
>
> ```
> // #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -lfoo
> ```
>
> Will be expanded to:
>
> ```
> // #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/go/src/foo/libs -lfoo
> ```

Comment: you can't use relative paths in LDFLAGS, because the build happens in a different directory than the source. That's why I mentioned `{SRCDIR}` above`

Comment: @JimB both  `-L${SRCDIR}/libs`  and `-L./libs`  works here for me, so edited to general case: `-L${SRCDIR}/libs`.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, literally you have just made my day! Sorry for being dim its been a fair few years since I have done any C.

Comment: @Amd: it's probably because you're using `go build` with an assumed package of the current directory. You can't `go get` or `go install` with a relative path.